# Dojo Toolkit - How to change the color of a table column with a button?

Tags: javascript, datagrid, dojo

I am a complete beginner to dojo and have simply been following the tutorials on the website. Now I am trying to dynamically change the background color of a table when pressing a button. Here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
        <!-- load Dojo -->
        <script>dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true}</script>
        <script src="dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>
        <script> require(['myModule.js']); </script>

        <title>table</title>

    </head>

    <body class="claro">
        <h1 id="greeting">test table</h1>

    <table data-dojo-type="dojox.grid.DataGrid" id="tableContainer">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th field="col1">Company</th>
                <th field="col2">Contact</th>
                <th field="col3">Country</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                <td>Maria Anders</td>
                <td>Germany</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>

    <button id="progButtonNode" type="button"></button>
    <div id="result1"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is myModule.js file. When I click the button the function does not seem to work. When I use the commented out code it works fine

```
require(["dijit/form/Button", "dojo/dom", "dojo", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Button, dom){
    // Create a button programmatically:
    var myButton = new Button({
        label: "Click me!",
        onClick: function(dojo){
            //dom.byId("result1").innerHTML += "Thank you! ";
            dojo.style("tableContainer", "background-color", "red");
        }
    }, "progButtonNode").startup();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to apply the style on the node so

```
dojo.style(dom.byId("tableContainer"), "background-color", "red");
```

should work for you. Also other way is to change the css class. Let's say you have a css class which does what you want and you want to apply it onClick of a button. You can do something like

```
dijit.byId('yourgid').set('class','yourcssclass');
```

You can also use onStyleRow event ro style your rows